# Ошибка с функцией header()

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, пишу авторизацию в админке.
Проверяю введенную информацию, если все ок, то присваиваю `$_SESSION` значение и обновляю страницу с помощью `header()`.
И тут же вылазит ошибка:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at Z:homesocwwwadminindex.php:12) in Z:homesocwwwadminindex.php on line 60

На 12 строке у меня находится проверка переменной `$_SESSION`, которую я передал.
Гуглил, все, что нагуглил, не помогло. Все файлы в UTF-8 без BOM.

```
 <?
session_start();
?>
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Админка</title>
    <link href="../css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
  <body>
<div class="carcas">
<div class="top_bar">
<? if(!isset($_SESSION['logged'])){ ?>
            <form class="login_form" method="POST" action="index.php">
                <table >
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>    
                            <td>Логин :</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="login"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Пароль:</td>
                            <td><input type="password" name="password"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                            <input class="submit_login_form" type="submit" name="submit" value="Войти"/>
            </form>
    <?}else{?>
    <div class="exit">
        <a href="exit.php">Выход</a>    
    </div>
    <?}?>

<?
require_once('../class/config_db.php');
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged'])){
    if($_POST['submit']){
        $error = true;

        if(empty($_POST['login'])){
            print_r('<h2 style="color : red;"> Вы не ввели логин ! </h2>');
            $error = false;
        }

        if(empty($_POST['password'])){
            print_r('<h2 style="color : red;"> Вы не ввели пароль ! </h2>');
            $error = false;
        }

        $login = $_POST['login'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if($error){
            $result = $db->SELECT(array('username','password'),'user');
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            if($row['username'] == $login & $row['password'] == $password){
                $_SESSION['logged'] = $login;

                    print_r('<a href="index.php">Обновить</a>');
                    header('Refresh: 5');

            }else{
                echo 'Логин или пароль введены неверно';    
            }
        }

    }else{

    }

}else{
 ?>
</div>
<div class="content">

</div>  
<?
}
?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Заголовки отправлять нужно до вывода любого текста, т.е вот эта часть кода `if(!isset($_SESSION['logged']))` должна идти до всех тегов. Cделай проверку до тега `<html>`, если все ок, то делай header.

Answer (score 2):

Запомните важное правило построения любого веб-приложения:

1. Сначала php-код
2. Потом разметка страницы.

2 строго не должно быть в 1. MVC в помощь.

А по теме, то уже ответили, `header()` должен быть до любого вывода, и кодировка страницы должна быть UTF-8 без BOM.